# MinGW32-make path variable issue

Tags: c, windows, cmd, mingw32

I am trying to build a C project on Win10 and i am using MinGW32-make. Prior to build the build directories should be created, and this is where build breaks with following output:

```
mkdir build\f2803x
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, mkdir build\f2803x, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
Makefile:64: recipe for target 'build\f2803x' failed
mingw32-make: *** [build\f2803x] Error 2
```

I've tried running the mkdir command from the command line and it runs successfuly, however when i try running mingw32-make it fails. I've been searcing the web and one answer to the similar question pointed out that PATH in for the Mingw32-make and PATH for the windows may not be the same, so i added echo path to the makefile and compared the output to `echo %PATH%` from the cmd. It appears that they are not the same. Mingw32-make has
`/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/user123/bin` that is not stated anywhere in any of the windows environment variables. I've also searched the registry as a last resort, however this is not in registry either. Where can these additional paths come from, and is it even the issue of the path?

Comment: You need to run `cmd.exe /c mkdir build\f2803x`.  `Mkdir` is a built-in command in `cmd.exe`, not a program you can run from `CreateProcess()`.

Answer (score 1):

mkdir is not a program, it's a built-in command interpreted by `cmd.exe`.
You want:

cmd.exe /c mkdir build\f2803x

Answer (score 0):

I've been chasing a similar problem. For me the error was due to a missing command (I didn't have a `date` command available). Check your path and make sure that your make can find the mkdir command. Also, make sure you are executing a *nix style mkdir, not the dos/windows mkdir.

Comment: A *nix style mkdir is not necessary.

Comment: OK, I get it now. the `CreateProcess(NULL, command, ...)` is because the program doesn't exist. In the case of `cmd.exe` there is no mkdir command because it's built in. Thanks for the clarification.